# Probability, geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the probability of $P(X<E(X))$ if $X$ has a geometric distribution such that $P(X=1)=0.25$.

I found $E(X)=0.25$. I guess I should find $P(X=0)$, but I don't know how. I can only plug $k>0$ values in the mass function.

Comment: The geometric distribution is the probability distribution of the number $X$ of Bernoulli trials needed to get one success, supported on the set $\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$
\Pr\{X=k\}=(1-p)^{k-1}p
$$
for $k\ge1$ and
$$
\Pr\{X=1\}=(1-p)^0p=p=0.25
$$
so that
$$
\operatorname EX=\frac1p=4.
$$
We obtain that
$$
\Pr\{X<\operatorname EX\}=\Pr\{X<4\}=\sum_{k=1}^3\Pr\{X=k\}=\sum_{k=1}^3(0.75)^{k-1}0.25\approx0.5781.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I remembered wrongly. I thought that the expactation of the geometrix distribution equals $p$.

Comment: @kanbhold I'm glad I could help! You can check the properties of the geometric distribution [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).